# Django logger started intermittently failing to write to a file

Tags: python, logging, file-io

I have logging set up in my Django site using python's logger that has been working fine for many months.

Since the last couple of days, it has started failing in the following way:

The log file shows has a line which has stopped being written part-way through, immediately followed by the next line. Example:

```
2012-12-17 16:42012-12-17 17:05:06,403
```

Also, there is a significant time gap between the failed write and the write which suceeded on the same line, when normally a line is written every minute or so.

This problem has occurred 6 times in the last 3 days.

Here is my logger config:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': { 
    'analytics': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': METRICS_LOGFILE,            
        'formatter': 'analytics',
    },
},
'formatters': {
    'analytics': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'analytics': {
        'handlers': ['analytics'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },            
}
```

}